# Can we have retain property with no getter and setters on Obj C elements?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, optimization, encapsulation

Ok, so I was reading some articles regarding **Good Programming Practices** and I came across a statement which said that **making all your Elements public for your classes isn't a good idea.. aka The concept of Encapsulation**.

Now in Objective C, When I create a element for my class, I do the following, consider an NSMutableArray

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray* myArray;
```

**WHY I DO THIS?**

So as to give the Retain property to myArray and therefore, giving it a simpler Memory Management cycle. Later on, I initialize the myArray in viewDidLoad as

```
self.myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];
```

Later in Dealloc...

```
self.myArray = nil;
```

**WHAT ELSE HAPPENS**

By giving this property and synthesizing myArray in .m file, what I am unknowingly doing is **making Public Getters and Setters** for all the elements of my class.

Also, the auto-generated UI Elements from Xib files, do have the same declarations applied.

That isn't a nice idea to keep creating public Getters and setters for each and every element of your class, right?

So, there's absolutely no kind of encapsulation applied! Please correct me if I am wrong here and help me with any solutions!

Thanks!

Comment: You can declare a property in `.m` file to make it invisible from outside.

Comment: @Stas : But then how do I manage its memory management cycle? I guess giving properties to each element is the best way!

Comment: @Stas: even Apple suggest to declare only properties and forget about ivars. It is much simpler to only declare properties, and declare no ivar at all (LLVM will declare backing variables for you if necessary) because everything (memory mgmt but also atomicity and KVO) is automatically managed then. _(You may in rare case prefer ivars over properties for optimization purposes, but in general that's not worth it)_

Comment: didn't know that! Many thanks, will use your answer as guide!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use the principle of [**Class Extensions**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW2) that allows you to put part of your declarations in your `.m` file, thus making it invisible in your header and invisible from other classes.

*(This is Apple's recommended way to declare private methods and properties, by the way)*

***`YourClass.h`***

```
@interface MyClass : MySuperclass
// public properties
// public methods
@end
```

***`YourClass.m`***

```
@interface MyClass()
// This is a class extension
// put here private properties
// and private methods too
@end

@implementation MyClass
// And your implementation of course here
@end
```

You can even declare a property as readonly in your public interface (in the header file) and redeclare it as readwrite in your private interface (in the class extension in the `.m` file) for example.

**See [the Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW2) for more details**.

---

Note that:

- There is NO NEED to declare the instance variable if you declare the property: the compiler will generate it automatically for you so you don't have to bother and to declare it in the `.h`. In the latest version of the compiler (Modern Objective-C) there is even no need for the `@synthesize` directive as it now generate it automatically if not present (see doc)
- If you prefer to declare instance variables anyway, you can also do this in the class extension in your `.m` the same way you would do in your `.h`. That's a way to hide instance variables from the public header too. In general I really rarely use instance variables (as declaring only the properties is sufficient) and if I really need an ivar I declare it in the class extension to make it not visibile in the public header.

Answer (score 3):

You can declare the property in your class.m file, so the getter and setter methods are accessible only in that class. An example:

**MyClass.h**

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
    NSMutableArray *_myArray;
}
@end
```

**MyClass.m**

```
@interface MyClass ()
    @property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *myArray;
@end


@implementation MyClass

[... MyClass implementation ..]

@synthesize myArray = _myArray;
@end
```

So you can use "self.myArray" only in "MyClass.h" file.

Comment: Note that there is no nooed to declare the ivar in the `.h` if you declare the property. The compiler will generate the backing instance variable associated with your property for you if it does not exists already. _(And if you really need/want to declare instance variables in addition to the property, you can do it in the class extension in the `.m` file too, to hide it from the public header anyway)_

Comment: Yes, thanks. Writing the answer I use my default declaration, but the user can follow your suggestion too :)